# Quasiconvexity property of quasinorms

Tags: reference-request, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, norms, operator-norms

Schatten $p$ norm is convex when $p\geq1$ holds and if $p\in(0,1)$ it is quasinorm.

1. If $p\in(0,1)$ then is Schatten $p$ norm quasi convex? I am interested in definition of quasi convexity here https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1716350 and here http://www.numdam.org/item/COCV_2008__14_4_795_0.
2. Is there a general criterion when quasinorms are quasiconvex?

Is there a good reference on quasi convex matrix norms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, quasinorms are in general not quasiconvex. (Well, this is true if quasiconve means that the levelsets of the function are convex; other defintions of quasiconvexity may exist…)

By positive homogeneity, a (quasi)norm is completely described by one of its levelsets. If this levelset is convex (and fulfills some other technical conditions) the function is actually a norm, but the property that separates norm from quasinorms is the convexity of the levelsets.

For the specific question: The Schatten $p$-quasinorm of a diagonal matrix with positive entries on the diagonal is the $p$-quasinorm of the diagonal entries and thus, for $0<p<1$, the Schatten quasinorm is not quasiconvex.

Comment: Modifieded with reference of quasiconvexity of interest.

Comment: Now I am confused. One link defines quasiconvexity in the way I used it, the other defines quasiconvexity in another way which is applicable to functions of a matrix argument. Which one are you interested in?

Comment: I am interested in matrix schatten norm sorry for being unclear.

Comment: I got that, but which notion of *quasiconvexity* are you interested in? There are at least two different meanings (and you linked both of them).

Comment: I am interested in the convex programming case.

Comment: Well, then my answer applies. Schatten p is not quasiconvex.

Comment: Would you know any of queries here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/311271/rank-1-approximation-by-minimizing-sum-of-nuclear-norm-of-2-times-2-submatri?

Comment: do you think you know any of queries there?